# Python unittest not running from specified directory

Tags: python-3.x, unit-testing, filepath

If I run this comamnd inside `app`, I get this errors that that there is no such file or directory:

```
python3 -m unittest discover -t ~/app/dataloader/  -s ~/app/dataloader/tests
```

results in this error:

```
  with open("assertions/validator/validation_config.json") as inp:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'assertions/validator/validation_config.json'
```

However, if I cd into `dataloader` and run this:

```
python3 -m unittest discover -t .  -s tests
```

everything passes.

Is this strange?

The app folder structure is `app -> dataloader -> assertions -> validator -> validation_config.json`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the `-t` and `-s` options of `unittest discover` correspond to `top_level_dir` and `start_dir` parameters of [`unittest.TestLoader.discover`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestLoader.discover) respectively.

> Find all the test modules by recursing into subdirectories from the specified start directory, and return a TestSuite object containing them...
>
> All test modules must be importable from the top level of the project. If the start directory is not the top level directory then the top level directory must be specified separately.

So the two options control how `unittest` finds and imports modules when testing. However, they don't seem to affect how the program searches files during runtime. If you print [`os.listdir()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.listdir) out before loading `validation_config.json`, you'll see that only the latter case is able to find it with the relative path.

To solve the problem, you can amend that line to absolute path by using [`os.path.abspath`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.abspath) like:

```py
# Get the absolute path of this current test script
base_path, _ = os.path.split(os.path.abspath(__file__))
# Form the absolute path of the needed json
json_path = os.path.join(base_path, "../assertions/validator/validation_config.json")

with open(json_path) as inp:
    validation_config = json.load(inp)
```

Then your former case should work as well.